# Event Calendar in Umbraco Backoffice

Tags: umbraco7, backoffice, all-in-one-event-calendar

I want to implement calendar functionality in Umbraco backoffice which has features similar to google calendar where admin can schedule Appointments or events.
I want the following features in calendar/Scheduler at the time of adding task/Event :

- Setting TimeZone
- Setting Resources
- Setting Recurrence Pattern
- Setting Start and End Time

I have seen "**Event Calendar**" package in umbraco but as it is for front end users i am not looking anything like that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Allow me to be the Devil's advocate here and ask why you'd want this functionality in (specifically) Umbraco?

Comment: @JannikAnker We already have developed an application in Umbraco and now we have requirement of managing resources (i.e. community hall in one town) its booked and free time slots etc. CMS Admin will approve and manage the resources from the Backend. He/She can upload the available time for public and book any slot after they receive appointment request from the users.